# What is the point of using private variables if we also use the property decorator in Python?

Tags: python, class

Consider the following class:

```
class Product:

    def __init__(self, entity_id, name, price):
        self.entity_id = entity_id
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
```

We can just access and change the attributes of an instance of the Product class. So we can do something like this:

```
product1 = Product(1, "p1", 100)
product1.name = "p2"
```

And we can change that attribute directly. We might not want that, so we can use double underscore to prevent this:

```
class Product:

    def __init__(self, entity_id, name, price):
        self.__entity_id = entity_id
        self.__name = name
        self.__price = price
```

And now we cannot access those attributes directly anymore. We need to use the getter and setter methods that we define within the class. The following wouldn't work:

```
product1 = Product(1, "p1", 100)
product1.__name = "p2"    # we can't do this
```

So this is why we define something like this within the class:

```
def set_name(self, name):
    self.__name = name
```

And we call this method outside the class to change the name. We can't change that attribute directly, we have to use the setter method.

If we were to use properties:

```
class Product:

    def __init__(self, entity_id, name, price):
        self.__entity_id = entity_id
        self.__name = name
        self.__price = price

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self.__name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, name):
        self.__name = name
```

The attributes are still private, but we can change the private attribute `name` by just doing this:

```
product1 = Product(1, "p1", 100)
product1.name = "p2"
```

So then, my question is: What is the point of using private variables if we can just change them directly, now that we used properties? I thought the point of private variables is to prevent direct access to the attributes of a class instance directly, so that we can't (directly) change them outside the scope of the class, we'd have to use a getter/setter. But if we use properties, all of that goes out the window. We can change the attributes outside the scope of the class. So what is the point of using private variables if we also use the property decorator in Python? I don't know if I made my question clear, I'm really confused about this.

Comment: If all your property is doing is setting and getting the attribute without any checks or side effects, then it is unnecessary and you might as well allow access to the attribute directly. The point of them is that you can do something more complicated if necessary.

Comment: Your understanding is not correct. A single underscore make an attribute "private by convention". Double underscores make it subject to name mangeling. Both do not prevent access from outside.

Comment: I think your professor was probably trying to show to much stuff at the same time, confusing you in the process. As already pointed out, the underscores are just part of a convention, showing intent of the author that this member-variable/method is not meant for usage outside the class. Decorators are something else entirely: They are `callables` that return `callables`. In other words, a function that takes another function as an argument, adds functionality to it and returns it. This tutorial is quite good: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/decorator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think like this:

Define your attribute as public `name`, because well, there is way to make it private in Python.

```
class Product:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

*If `name` is an implementation detail of your class*, hint that to the class users by renaming it to `_name`. Nothing changes, this is only a convention saying, "this is for internal use only, and can change in the future; do not touch, or go ahead at your own risk".

```
class Product:
    
        def __init__(self, name):
            self._name = name
```

If you want to *annoy* a bit your class users, rename it to `__name`. This is discouraged by many Pythonists, because it does not prevent access, it justs causes an error on direct access (this is actually meant to mangle the name with the class name to prevent clashes, not give privacy).

```
class Product:
    
        def __init__(self, name):
            self.__name = name

>>> p = Product("Cube")
>>> p.__name
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Product' object has no attribute '__name'
>>> p._Product__name
'Cube'
```

Instead, and if you want to make an attribute read-only, define a property `name`, changing the the underlying `name` to `_name` (the internal class value you return in your getter).

```
class Product:
    
        def __init__(self, name):
            # hint privacy only, using _ 
            self._name = name

        @property
        def name(self):
            return self._name
```

If you actually want it to be changed too, define the property setter, making it writable on one hand, and allowing the execution of validation code, a common requirement when you allow writes. Both the getter and the setter can be used to intercept attribute access at runtime, and run additional code with whatever class internal side effects you might need.

```
       @name.setter
       def name(self, value):
           # maybe validate the value
           if name_is_valid(value):
               self._name = value
           else:
               raise ValueError("Invalid Product name")
```

This is what you actually need to know to use properties most of the time, without having to worry about [decorators and descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-decorator) (an advanced concept, properties are actually a descriptor).